# How to create UWP application using angular

Tags: uwp

I tried the following steps but its not working.

1. Using Angular cli created sample project

   - `npm install -g @angular/cli`
   - `ng new my-dream-app`
2. I created and UWP Project using visualstudio 2017 (File->New->JavaScript->WindowsUniversal->BlankApp(Universal Windows)->ok) and included sample angular project created using above step.

3)Change the start page location inside package.appxmanifest file(Application -> Start page) src/index.html

4)Run the project by pressing button in the visual studio

5)Create App package and install it in Windows10 compatible os(Project -> store -> create app package) that also not working

Can anyone please explain what I done wrong.

I referred the below video link but its not clearly explained:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/JavaScript-Webinar-Series/Building-a-Universal-Windows-Platform-app-using-Angular/Building-a-Universal-Windows-Platform-app-using-Angular

Answer (score 0):

It is not the correct way to use Angular in UWP.

create Angular App

```
-> npm install -g @angular/cli
-> ng new my-dream-app
```

navigate inside the project and create the production build

```
-> cd my-dream-app
-> ng build --prod
```

include the files created inside the dist folder(production build)in your UWP project and try to run the application in visual studio it works.